# How to add "," in regular expression to send multiple mail in objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, xcode

I am new on iOS and I am facing problem regarding add `,` in the regular expression.

My code is like this

```
 NSString *emailRegEx = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,100}";        
NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx];
```

If I add `,` in the regular expression app get crash

```
 NSString *emailRegEx = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-,]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-,]+\\.[A-Za-z,]{2,100}";
 NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx];
```

Error is like this

> NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Can't do regex matching,
>   reason: Can't open pattern U_REGEX_INVALID_RANGE (string
>   abc@gmail.com,xyz@gmail.com, pattern
>   [A-Z0-9a-z._%+-,]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-,]+.[A-Za-z,]{2,100}, case 0, canon
>   0)'

Did some one face this type of issue?I need to send multiple emails.
Thanks in Advance!

Comment: @WiktorStribixew It is not because I ask multiple mail and your link is for single mail validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't simply separate the string using `,` and compare each string is valid email or not.

```
NSString *emailRegEx = @"[A-Z0-9a-z._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}";
NSPredicate *emailTest = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"SELF MATCHES %@", emailRegEx];
NSArray *emails = [emailField.text componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
NSMutableArray *valiedEmails = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSString *email in emails) {
    if ([emailTest evaluateWithObject:email]) {
        [valiedEmails addObject: email];            
    }
}
if (valiedEmails.count > 0) {
    txtviewemailaddress.text = [valiedEmails componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
    [self serverconnectionPost];
} 
else {
    //show alert that email is not valid 
}
```

Comment: It is in one textfiled only. It is not accepting this type of validation [A-Z0-9a-z._%+-,]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-,]+\\.[A-Za-z,]{2,100}"

Comment: @Muju Check the edited answer and change the regx to compare only one email at a time and the separate email from field by `,`  and then loop through the result and compare each one is valid or not

Comment: @Muju Check the edited answer and compare a single email at a time, so make regx to compare only one email not multiple with coma separated.

Comment: But I need to compare multiple email at a time.

Comment: @Muju Don't you can achieve that in for loop ?

Comment: Because client want to enter all email at same time.

Comment: @Muju What I'm saying is you can break the text with `,` separator and compare each coma separated string that it is valid emil or not?

Comment: Ok. I will try that.Can you please share some more code for that?

Comment: it is calling method multiple times.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145172/discussion-between-nirav-d-and-muju).

Comment: `,` is a valid character in an email address.  See section 3.4 of RFC 2822.  If you're users are copy/pasting email addresses from other sources, you need to consider the spec.  https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2822#section-3.4

Comment: @bbum I have never written anything in my solution that says the `,` is invalid character. I have just proposed solution with simplest way nothing more than that.

Comment: @NiravD By relying on `[emailField.text componentsSeparatedByString:@","]`, you're making a claim that `,` will only be used to separate full and valid email addresses.   Or you're code is going to have to deal with the fallout of violating RFC2822.

Comment: @NiravD I am not able to add email like this abc.xyz@google.co.in I want to add email id like this how can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

While adding the comma `,` to the character class, make sure you move the hyphen `-` to the end, or escape it `\-`. Here are 3 ways to fix the error:

- `[A-Za-z0-9.,-]` Move `-` to the end
- `[A-Za-z0-9.\-,]` Escaped the hyphen `\-`
- `[A-Za-z0-9,-.]` Fix the order. This includes a range (ASCII 44 to 46) which will include another character which is actually nothing by hyphen itself `-` so it is same as above two regexes!

**Why do you need to do this?**

If you leave a hyphen between 2 characters in a character class, the engine tries to match the range `.-,` which is an invalid ASCII Range (46 to 44). However if you had written `,-.` it would work fine and not give any error since it is ASCII 44 to 46, however it would include another ASCII character which is 45th (`-` itself)

Hope this helps

Comment: no not working.

Comment: I add [A-Z0-9a-z._%+,-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.,-]+\\.[A-Za-z.,-]{2,100}      but not work